# Jest setup for typescript with module resolution

Tags: typescript, webpack, jestjs

The project is using ReactJS, Typescript, Webpack and Jest.
To achieve module resolution (to minimize import), we made following changes:

`TSConfig.js:`

`"compilerOptions": { "baseUrl": "src",}`

`Webpack.config.js`

```
alias: {
  Common: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/Common/'),
},
```

The code works fine, however Jest tests started failing with error:

`Cannot find module 'Common/js/utils' from 'MyContact.ts'`

This is because, Jest is not yet aware of how to resolve Common to Src/common and not to look in node_module. To fix this, following change were made:

`jestConfig.js`

`moduleNameMapper: {"Common": "<rootDir>/src/Common"}`

That seems fixed, but then I have another issue [which is why I am here :)]

Jest encountered an unexpected token

```
This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

C:\Users\ua\Project\develop\src\Common\index.ts:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from './Acc'
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
```

Here is full jest.config.js file:

```js
module.exports = {
  verbose: false,
  roots: ["<rootDir>/src"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
  },
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      diagnostics: false
    }
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$":
      "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
    "\\.(css|less|pcss)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js",
    "Common": "<rootDir>/src/Common",
  },
  snapshotSerializers: ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/setupEnzyme.ts"],
  testMatch: [ "**/__tests__/**/*.test.[jt]s?(x)", "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)"],
  collectCoverageFrom: ["**/*.{ts,tsx}", "!**/node_modules/**", "!**/vendor/**"]
};
```

tsconfig.js:

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./custom_typings"
    ],
    "outDir": "build",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": [ "dom", "es2015", "es2017", "esnext" ],
    "noEmit": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types",
    "./custom_typings"
  ],
  "exclude":[
    "./node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/*",
    "custom_typings"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Code for some reason has a non-top-level export statement, which is illegal. If you wrote it that way, you'll need to change it. If it's the output of a tool or process, you'll need to debug that process.

Comment: which code you are talking about, jest.config.js? Also just so you know, the code is running fine, it's just jest throwing this issue.

Comment: I'm talking about the error you yourself posted: `function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from './Acc'`. You cannot have an export statement inside a function body. Imports/exports have to be statically resolvable. There is a proposal for an `import` function that returns a Promise, but that export statement is flat out illegal any way you slice it. The error message points you right to it.

Comment: no, my code does not contain this function it is like: ```export * from './Async'``` Plain and simple series of export statements.

Comment: This is come from node_modules currently node.js doesn't esm support so we have to add babel-jest package

Comment: Do you have module set to commonjs or es2015 in your tsconfig?

Comment: @JaredSmith if that makes sense then can you pls remove -1 vote of the question?

Comment: @JaredSmith, I have added full tsconfig.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so I was able to fix module resolution by adding this line to jest.config.js

`moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src"],`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like babel by default can't parse typescript test file, so do install `npm install ts-jest babel-jest --save-dev` Then add below config in jest.config.js file.

```
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': require.resolve('babel-jest'),
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  }
```

Comment: We have this in jest.config.js. The problem is that as I am using module resolution, Jest is not able to resolve non node-module imports.

Comment: Added at the end of the question.

Comment: Code for some reason has a non-top-level export statement. No amount of transforming is going to fix that.

Comment: does it mean I have to install babel-jest? Currently I do not have it.

Comment: Yes you have to install "npm install babel-jest --save-dev"

Comment: didn't fix, as babel-jest is for jsx, I am typescript guy :(

Comment: Can you try like this  '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest'

Comment: @RajaJaganathan, could it be that `"Common/$": "<rootDir>/src/Common",` is not considering deep path like `Common/js/util/`? if so, how can we update it to consider all the detailed path?